# Get relative path of a parent's subfolder

Tags: windows, batch-file, filepath

I had a massive batch file which I split into several smaller ones, with one master file calling each of the smaller files individually. For neatness I put the individual scripts in a subfolder from the project folder (the master script is in the project folder).

This has however has caused an issue - I can't work out how to change some paths in the new individual scripts. Here is approximately what layout is like:

```
Project
|---MasterScript.bat
|   
|---Scripts
|   |---scriptA.bat
|   
|---Exes
|   |---program.exe
|   |---config.xml
```

So the master script calls each of the batch scripts - `A` and script `A` calls `program.exe` with argument `/config config.xml`.

The issue is how to address `program.exe` and `config.xml`.

I unfortunately have just hacked these scripts together without really knowing how batch file paths are resolved, and so have literally no idea how to write relative paths using the parent folder etc. relationships.

So essentially I am asking in general how to write relative batch paths and specifically how to write these paths.

Comment: Write `~dp0..\Exes\program.exe` in batch script `scriptA.bat` to point to `program.exe`; type `call /?` into a command prompt window to find out what `%~dp0` means...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%~dp0` expands to drive and path of argument 0 which is the batch file itself. This file path reference expands always to a path with a backslash. Try it out with a batch file containing only

```
@echo off
echo Batch file path is: "%~dp0"
pause
```

How to reference arguments (parameters, options) of a batch file without or with a modifier is described in help output on running `call /?` in a command prompt window on several display pages.

Short relative path tutorial:

1. Paths starting with name of a directory or a file name are relative to **current directory**.
2. Paths starting with `.\` are also relative to **current directory**.
3. Paths starting with `..\` reference the **parent directory of current directory**.
4. Paths starting with just `\` are relative to **root directory of current DRIVE**.
   For example `\Windows` references the directory `Windows` in root of current drive independent on which directory is the current directory.

`.\` and `..\` can be also used one or more times nearly anywhere within a path. `.\` and `..\` can't be used left to drive letter and colon as this would mean a directory in current or parent directory is specified which contains a colon in name which is not possible.

The usage of `..\..\` or even more `..\` in sequence helps to reference a path 2 or more directories upwards in directory structure relative to current directory.

On just running applications it is absolutely valid to use `~dp0..\Exes\program.exe`.

It is also no problem to reference other directories or files with such a mixture of absolute and relative path components in arguments passed to an application or script.

But it is often helpful if the real absolute full path is determined from a pure relative path or a mixture of absolute and relative path before passing a directory or file name with path to an application or script for getting better readable warning and error messages containing the passed directory/file name.

The command **FOR** can be used to get full path of a directory or file from a relative path or a mixture of absolute and relative path.

Example:

```
@echo off
for /F %%I in ("%~dp0..\Exes") do set "FullExesPath=%%~fI"
echo Path to project executables: "%FullExesPath%"
pause
```

**Note:** There is no backslash at end of this resolved path. On using `%FullExesPath%` in a file reference the backslash must be typed between this directory reference and the file name which makes the string easier to read.

For details on command **FOR** run in a command prompt window `for /?` and read carefully the output help pages.